# How to get and display value from dropdown generated by foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have no solutions for this. Perhaps someone wiser than I can offer some help. This involves a MySQL table and displaying retrieved data in a form.

The objective is to display in a form what is currently stored in a particular row of data.

I am using the same form to insert and display data for modification. I generated dropdown options using the following code, which works fine.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pistol_model_brand">Pistol Model Brand</label>
  <select name="pistol_model_brand" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select one</option>
   <?php foreach($brands as $key => $brand): ?>
   <option value="<?php htmlout($key) ?>"><?php htmlout($brand); ?</option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

To show current stored data, I echo it into the form using value="content here".

Since my dropdown options are not actually listed, I do not know how to retrieve  the value stored in the DB table and display it in the form.

I normally do this:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Waist</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="waist">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="iwb" <?php if($item['waist'] === 'iwb') {echo htmlspecialchars(' selected');} ?>>IWB</option>
    <option value="owb" <?php if($item['waist'] === 'owb' || 'OWB') {echo htmlspecialchars(' selected');} ?>>OWB</option>
</select>
</div>
```

In this case, however, I don't know what to do, or what options I have.

Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This answer is predicated on the assumption from your use of the `$item` variable that you have the database row available in that variable and it contains the brand that is stored in the database for that row.

This is generally the approach I use when not using a template engine (like Laravel Blade or Twig):

```
<select name="pistol_model_brand" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select one</select>
   <?php foreach($brands as $key => $brand) : ?>
       <?php $selected = ($key == $item['brand'] ? 'selected' : '') ?>
       <option value="<?php echo($key); ?>" <?php echo($selected); ?>>
           <?php echo($brand); ?>
       </option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

The approach I use is to use a ternary operator to populate a `$selected` variable just before the option and output either `selected` or nothing. Its pretty ugly though!

Using something like Laravel Blade, it tends to look a little clearner:

```
<select name="pistol_model_brand" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select one</select>
   @foreach($brands as $key => $brand)
       <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ $item['brand'] ? 'selected' : '' }}>
           {{ $brand }}
       </option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

**EDIT:** Adding more detail...

```
$selected = ($key == $item['brand'] ? 'selected' : '');
```

The syntax of that is called a ternary operator. It has the format of `condition ? valueA : valueB` where *condition* returns a truthy or falsy value. If it is truthy, it will return *valueA*, and if it is falsy it will return *valueB*. What that means is the value of `$selected` will be either the string "selected" or an empty string, depending on whether `$key == $item['brand']` returns true or false.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply. I wish I could understand this.

Comment: $item contains the data for each field in the row [ $item = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);], so "yes" it has the data I want.

Comment: @JimB814 I added some more details on how the ternary operator works. You can read more about them here: https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/ternary-conditionals/

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I will examine your link.